# Need end-to-end suggestion to connect EC2 instance to on-premises jump host which is in another cloud or data center

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-vpc, aws-vpn

Actually I am having one use case like "I am having one ansible server in cloud for example EC2 instance and I am having one customer jump host in a data center or another cloud". I need to establish connection from ansible server to customer jump host.

I need some end-end suggestion to proceed with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to use a VPN.

Check out the following:

- [What is AWS Site-to-Site VPN?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html)
- [What is AWS Client VPN?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is AWS client VPN will work if the customer jump server is there in some other cloud or in there physical environment.

Comment: Client VPN is actually AWS version of a managed OpenVPN connect. If you can install the OpenVPN client on their machine then yes you can do that.